# KVS (session storage) で特定の値を変更する方法

Tags: javascript, html5

KVS 初心者です。 現在 sessionStorage をいじっています。

例えば

```
{id01:{hoge:1, moge:2, hige:5}}
```

といったレコードがあります。

この中の `moge` の値だけを `4` に変えたいのですが、いまのとこ `id01` の中身を全取得して `moge` の値を書き直し、また `id01` をまるごと再保存するしか思いつきません。

```
id01.moge = 4
```

といったやり方はできないのでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

どのように `sessionStorage` で `hash` を扱っているか分からないですが、基本的に `sessionStorage` は `key`、`value` 共に `String` 型です。

> Each Storage object provides access to a list of key/value pairs, which are sometimes called items. **Keys are strings**. Any string (including the empty string) is a valid key. **Values are similarly strings**.

http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#the-storage-interface

そのため、`value` に `hash` を保存する際も `String` として保存し（`JSON.stringify()`などで）、値を取得する際に複合（`JSON.parse()`などで）しているかと思います。

そのため、直接 `sessionStorage` 内の `value` をオブジェクトとして取り扱う事はできないため、一度取り出した後に、更新し再度保存する必要があるかと思います。（以下コードのように）

```
// 保存
var data = {id01:{hoge:1, moge:2, hige:5}};
sessionStorage.setItem('id01', JSON.stringify(data));

// 取得
var str = sessionStorage.getItem('id01');
var item = JSON.parse(str);
// 更新
item.moge = 4
sessionStorage.setItem('id01', JSON.stringify(item));
```